# How to start MidiSmtpServer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to use MidiSmtpServer to receive email in a Heroku application, and have been using the code on one of the examples that the documents show. However, I don't know where to put that code for the SMTP server to start after Puma, or where to put it for it to start at all. Using `on_worker_boot` in puma.rb doesnt work.

puma.rb:

```
# Puma can serve each request in a thread from an internal thread pool.
# The `threads` method setting takes two numbers: a minimum and maximum.
# Any libraries that use thread pools should be configured to match
# the maximum value specified for Puma. Default is set to 5 threads for minimum
# and maximum; this matches the default thread size of Active Record.
#
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests; default is 3000.
#
port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

# Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
#
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

# Specifies the `pidfile` that Puma will use.
pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }

# Specifies the number of `workers` to boot in clustered mode.
# Workers are forked web server processes. If using threads and workers together
# the concurrency of the application would be max `threads` * `workers`.
# Workers do not work on JRuby or Windows (both of which do not support
# processes).
#
# workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }

require "midi-smtp-server"
require "mail"
on_worker_boot do

  class MySmtpd < MidiSmtpServer::Smtpd
    def on_message_data_event(ctx)
      puts "[#{ctx[:envelope][:from]}] for recipient(s): [#{ctx[:envelope][:to]}]..."

      # Just decode message ones to make sure, that this message ist readable
      @mail = Mail.read_from_string(ctx[:message][:data])

      # handle incoming mail, just show the message source
      puts @mail.to_s
    end
  end

  # try to gracefully shutdown on Ctrl-C
  trap("INT") do
    puts "Interrupted, exit now..."
    exit 0
  end

  # Output for debug
  puts "#{Time.now}: Starting MySmtpd..."

  # Create a new server instance listening at localhost interfaces 127.0.0.1:2525
  # and accepting a maximum of 4 simultaneous connections
  server = MySmtpd.new(2525, "0.0.0.0", 4)

  # setup exit code
  at_exit do
    # check to shutdown connection
    if server # Output for debug
      puts "#{Time.now}: Shutdown MySmtpd..."    # stop all threads and connections gracefully

      server.stop
    end  # Output for debug

    puts "#{Time.now}: MySmtpd down!\n"
  end

  # Start the server
  server.start

  # Run on server forever
  server.join
end
# Use the `preload_app!` method when specifying a `workers` number.
# This directive tells Puma to first boot the application and load code
# before forking the application. This takes advantage of Copy On Write
# process behavior so workers use less memory.
#
# preload_app!

# Allow puma to be restarted by `rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Applications running on Heroku are containerized, and running an SMTP server in or with the web process is not possible.

You need to instead look at services that provide inbound mail delivery. If you're using Rails 6, follow the documentation to set up [ActionMailbox](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailbox_basics.html).